# Swift enum - constrain associated values

Tags: swift, enums, initialization

I have an enum that represents a line thickness that can either be a constant width, or a width relative to the size of the view it's in.

```
enum Thickness {
    case Constant(Float)    // where value ≥ 0
    case Relative(Float)    // where 0 ≤ value ≤ 1
}
```

Is there a way to build these associated value constraints into the enum type? I am currently using `didSet` property observers on properties of this type:

```
var lineThickness: Thickness {
    didSet {
        switch lineThickness {
            case let .Relative(x): lineThickness = .Relative(min(max(x, 0), 1))
            case let .Constant(x): lineThickness = .Constant(max(x, 0))
        }
    }
}
```

But it would be far neater if I could do this once for the whole type, and not replicate this observer for each property.

I know that I can create initialisers or methods for the enum, but I'm not sure if/how I could use that to constrain the associated value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, not the best in elegance, but at least it will save you from bugs due to forgetting the observers here and there ...

```
struct Thickness {
    enum Type {
        case Constant
        case Relative
    }
    let type: Type
    let value: Float

    init(type: Type, value: Float) {
        self.type = type;
        switch type {
            case .Constant:
                self.value = max(value, 0)
            case .Relative:
                self.value = min(max(value, 0), 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree it's not fantastically elegant - I really like how expressive the type is as an enum when creating variables, and it's a shame there doesn't seem to be a better way to do what I'm after. I suppose in specifying constraints it's going beyond what the enum type is really intended for. Or maybe it'll be possible in the future as the language develops.

Comment: Also, I hope you don't mind, but I refactored your switch statement (I think it reads a bit better this way, personally). If you hate it, feel free to roll back the edit :)